# rails datatables error sort descending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, sorting, datatables

I'm new to Rails. Running Rails 4, and gem ajax-datatables-rails.

I have a few instances of datatables that are working without issue, but one table has an error when I try to sort any column descending. I can click on the header of any column and sort ascending. But if I click on that header again I get the following error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Log shows this after getting the error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/datatables/animal_registration_datatable.rb:29:in `block in data'
  app/datatables/animal_registration_datatable.rb:25:in `data'
  app/controllers/animal_registrations_controller.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/animal_registrations_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

animal_registration_datatable.rb

```
class AnimalRegistrationDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base


include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari

  def sortable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    if breeder?
      @sortable_columns ||= %w(AnimalRegistration.created_at Animal.name Animal.tag_number AnimalRegistration.status)
    else
      @sortable_columns ||= %w(AnimalRegistration.created_at Animal.name Contact.last_name Contact.farm_name)
    end
  end

  def searchable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    if breeder?
      @searchable_columns ||= %w(Animal.name Animal.tag_number AnimalRegistration.status)
    else
      @searchable_columns ||= %w(AnimalRegistration.farm_name Animal.name Contact.last_name Contact.first_name AnimalRegistration.created_at)
    end
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      if breeder?
        {
          '0' => record.created_at.strftime('%x - ''%l:%m %p'),
          '1' => record.animal.name,
          '2' => record.animal.tag_number,
          '3' => record.status,
          'DT_RowId' => record.id
        }
      else
        {
          '0' => record.created_at.strftime('%x - ''%l:%m %p'),
          '1' => record.animal.try(:name),
          '2' => record.breeder_contact_id ? record.breeder_contact.last_name + ', '  + record.breeder_contact.first_name : "",
          '3' => record.breeder_contact_id ? record.breeder_contact.farm_name : "",
          '4' => record.datatable_row_controls,
          'DT_RowId' => record.id
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def user
     @user ||= options[:user] #if @user is null, set it to options[:user]
  end

  def breeder?
    ! user.organization
  end

  def status
    @status ||= options[:status]
    @status ||= "pending"
  end

  def get_raw_records
    if breeder?
      AnimalRegistration.where(user_id: user.id).includes(:animal).references(:animal).distinct
    else
      AnimalRegistration.where(organization_id: user.organization.id, status: status).includes(:animal, :breeder_contact).references(:animal, :breeder_contact).distinct
    end
  end

  # ==== Insert 'presenter'-like methods below if necessary
end
```

Note that I am logged in as a breeder (if breeder? = true). Note also that when logged in as org (if breeder? = false), this error does not occur.

From animal_registrations_controller.rb:

```
  def index
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json do
    render json: AnimalRegistrationDatatable.new(view_context, user: current_user, status: params[:status])
  end
end
```

end

animal_registrations.js.coffee:

```
    $ ->
  dt = $("table.animal-registrations.ajax-table")
  if dt.hasClass("org-admin")
    dtCols = [
      { data: '0' }
      { data: '1' }
      { data: '2' }
      { data: '3' }
      { data: '4', orderable: false }
    ]
  else
    dtCols = [
      { data: '0' }
      { data: '1' }
      { data: '2' }
      { data: '3' }
    ]

  $("table.animal-registrations.ajax-table").DataTable(
    processing: true
    serverSide: true
    ajax: $('table.animals').data('source')
    pagingType: 'full'
    pageLength: 20
    lengthChange: false
    language:
      search: "<i class='fa fa-search'/>"
      sFilterInput: "form-control input-lg"
    # drawCallback: (settings) ->
    #   bindAnimalRowClickDatatable()
    columns: dtCols
  )
```

Note that if dt.hasClass("org-admin") is false.

Lots of moving parts here. What I can't figure out is why it would work when sorted ascending but not descending.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what you get in the console? See the query that fail.... some like SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't exactly figure out the problem but I resolved it. I implemented a filter on the views where you can select what status to view. So the underlying query now includes something like WHERE status = "approved". Now the datatables sorting works. So apparently the problem had something to do with the status column. I'm not going to try to recreate the issue for troubleshooting at this time. I'm just thankful it's working.